# How do I save data from MySQL db to excel file as Number not text using Python

Tags: python, mysql, excel

Below is the script. I am pulling some data and save to Excel
In the output file, all column are marked "Number stored as Text"
What can I do in the script to change all columns to number (int)?
Thanks

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="...",port=...,user="...",passwd="...",db='...')
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
SELECT shopid,userid,count(orderid)as no_of_orders
from order_viw
group by shopid,userid
""")

data = cursor.fetchall()

rowNum = 2
col = 1
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet")

for shopid,userid,no_of_orders in data:
    sheet.cell(column=col, row=rowNum, value="%d" % shopid)
    sheet.cell(column=col+1, row=rowNum, value="%d" % userid)
    sheet.cell(column=col+2, row=rowNum, value="%d" % no_of_orders)
    rowNum += 1
wb.save('C:/example.xlsx')
db.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried str(shopid) str(userid) and str(no_of_orders) ?

Comment: What I mean is now all data is now stored as text. I want to change data type to integer.
results are the same when using value="%d" and value="%s"

Answer (score 0):

As a forewarning, I'm running on Linux, have not got a MySql database and I am using libreoffice to check the results.
With those caveats in place, the following looks like it works for me:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
rowNum = 2
col = 1
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet")
#data = [[42,1,43],[82,2,28]]
data = [['42','1','43'],['82','2','28']]
for shopid,userid,no_of_orders in data:
    sheet.cell(column=col, row=rowNum).value=int(shopid)
    sheet.cell(column=col+1, row=rowNum).value=int(userid)
    sheet.cell(column=col+2, row=rowNum).value=int(no_of_orders)
    rowNum += 1
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

[image: Result]